# Using html helpers in Razor web helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to create a Razor web helper something like this :

```
@helper DisplayForm() {    
    @Html.EditorForModel();    
}
```

But this gives the error `"CS0103: The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context"`.

Is there any way to reference html helpers within web helpers?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can cast the static Page property from the context to the correct type:

```
@helper MyHelper() {
    var Html = ((System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage)WebPageContext.Current.Page).Html;

    Html.RenderPartial("WhatEver");
    @Html.EditorForModel();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me.  Now can anyone answer the question of why the `System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper` version exists at all?

Comment: You can always add this at the top of your file:

`@functions {
    public static System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<object> Html = ((System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage)WebPageContext.Current.Page).Html;
}`

Given that you can use `@Html` as everywhere else.

Answer (score 4):

Declarative helpers in Razor are static methods. You could pass the Html helper as argument:

```
@helper DisplayForm(HtmlHelper html) {
    @html.EditorForModel(); 
}

@DisplayForm(Html)
```

Comment: When I try this I get the error "CS1061: 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'EditorForModel' and no extension method 'EditorForModel' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: That's because your view needs to be strongly typed: `@model MyNs.Models.FooViewModel`.

Answer (score 1):

Razor inline WebHelper is generate static method.

So can not access instance member.

```
@helper DisplayForm(HtmlHelper html){
    @html.DisplayForModel()
}
```

How about this?