# Calling extension helpers from inline helpers - how?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I read this [[useful article]](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/03/23/comparing-mvc-3-helpers-using-extension-methods-and-declarative-razor-helper.aspx) that says I can create a library of inline helpers by putting them in a view in the special folder App_Code.  When I moved my `@helper` functions there, calls to extension helpers I have stopped working.  I read [[in this SO article]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032490/using-html-helpers-in-razor-web-helper) that there's an issue because the `@helper`s are static but my extensions are not... I tried the 2 different ways but cannot make it work.  It fails to recognise the existence of my extension helpers.

```
'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Image'
```

my extension helper is called 'Image'.  What should I be looking for?

Comment: It would be helpful to see which 2 ways you've tried.  Did you use the full path to your helper like this: @CustomHelpers.Truncate(ViewBag.Message, 8) in which case you don't need a "using" for the CustomHelpers.cshtml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, my problem had to do with namespace... so I have in \Views\Shared\HtmlHelpers.cs:

```
public static class Html
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, object htmlAttrs = null)
    {
```

which I generally access from my pages like this:

```
@Html.Image("/path/to/image")
```

in App_Code\Helpers.cshtml:

```
@helper AddButton(string path)
{
    var Html = ((System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage) WebPageContext.Current.Page).Html;
    @Html.Image(path);
}
```

but Intellisense would underline the "Image" and complain:

```
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<object>' does not contain a definition for 'Image'
and no extension method 'Image' accepting a first argument of type 
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<object>' could be found (are
you missing a directive or an assembly reference?)
```

the reason seemed to be that the Helpers.cshtml needs to have `@using` for the namespace... on my regular pages the namespace is included in my web.config but this page seems exempt from that mechanism

Answer (score 1):

When you write the Helperextension in razor view.
You need to call it like FileName.Method.

eg you have CustomHelpers.cshtml file in app_code and in that you have a method

```
     @helper TruncateString(string input, int length)
     {        
        if (input.Length <= length)
        {      
            @input        
        }
        else
        { 
          @input.Substring(0, length)<text>...</text>        
        }
    }
```

you can call it from index.cshtml

```
    @CustomHelpers.TruncateString("Example", 8);
```

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of example, the following code use the "RenderPage" function within a helper library:

```
@helper GetSection(string sectionName, string sectionTitle, string sectionFileName){
    <div id="@sectionName">
        <h1>@sectionTitle</h1>
        @System.Web.WebPages.WebPageContext.Current.Page.RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/MySections/" + @sectionFileName)
    </div>
}
```

It demonstrate how to retrieve the "**current page**" (context sensitive) instance.

This code works fine from within your own "common library" Razor helper file (".cshtml") situated in the "*app_code*" subfolder of your project.