# Html.ActionLink cannot be used in global Razor helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've created a global .cshtml Razor file in the App_Code folder of my MVC project to declare @helper functions. The problem is I can't use Html.ActionLink (or the other extensions) in the helper functions. I have tried to import the classes via a @using but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710853/using-mvc-htmlhelper-extensions-from-razor-declarative-views

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add the following line to your helper, to define `Html`

```
  var Html = ((System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage)WebPageContext.Current.Page).Html;
```

[(Copied from this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032490/using-html-helpers-in-razor-web-helper/4278128#4278128)

Comment: Thanks, too bad there isn't a nicer solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Further to the accepted answer, to make @Html available throughout the helper file:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html 

...

@functions {

    protected static new System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper Html
    {
        get
        {
            return ((System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage)WebPageContext.Current.Page).Html;    
        }
   }
}
```